# Turn off or fix Bounce Zoom warning from iPhone XIB compilation

Tags: iphone, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0, interface-builder

This has been annoying me for a while in several XCode projects.  I really don't like to have compiler warnings when I build.  When I build my current project, I get the following warning from a bunch of XIB files:

```
/.../CaseInformationView.xib:3:0 UIScrollView's 'Bounce Zoom' option will be ignored on iPhone OS versions prior to 2.1.
```

Since I'm building for 3.0, I don't care if it will be ignored.    If I want to use the Bounce Zoom option in my XIB file, how can I not see this warning?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In IB, select "Document Info" from the Window menu and set your Deployment target to 3.0.

EDIT: In more current versions of Xcode

1. Choose the xib
2. Go to the File Inspector
3. In the Interface Builder Document section, set Deployment and Development
4. Also, set Deployment Target on Project's Summary page (choose main project, then Summary tab)