# Just released to AppStore app crashing on iOS 3.0 incomprehensive archive

Tags: iphone, ios

Now I'm testing app on this phone and all just fine.

What the problem? on iOS 4.3 and 5.0 works fine

I'm using SDK iOS 5 (valid architectures set to armv6 and armv7)

**EDIT** this iOs device is jail broken. Can it be source of the problem?

**EDIT 2** I've get stack. This is appeared in release configuration

```
#0  0x31dd594c in __kill ()
#1  0x31dd5940 in kill ()
#2  0x31dd5934 in raise ()
#3  0x31deccfe in abort ()
#4  0x374ef848 in __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() ()
#5  0x300166c0 in _objc_terminate ()
#6  0x374ecf3c in __cxxabiv1::__terminate(void (*)()) ()
#7  0x374ecfb4 in std::terminate() ()
#8  0x374ed0dc in __cxa_throw ()
#9  0x300165e4 in objc_exception_throw ()
#10 0x30224026 in +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] ()
#11 0x30223fc6 in +[NSException raise:format:] ()
#12 0x305564b4 in -[NSKeyedUnarchiver initForReadingWithData:] ()
#13 0x3094927c in -[UINib instantiateWithOptions:owner:loadingResourcesFromBundle:] ()
#14 0x30949090 in -[NSBundle(NSBundleAdditions) loadNibNamed:owner:options:] ()
#15 0x308f131c in -[UIApplication _loadMainNibFile] ()
#16 0x308f0f9c in -[UIApplication _runWithURL:sourceBundleID:] ()
#17 0x309374b0 in -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] ()
#18 0x30936cf0 in -[UIApplication sendEvent:] ()
#19 0x3093687c in _UIApplicationHandleEvent ()
#20 0x3204696c in PurpleEventCallback ()
#21 0x30254a76 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#22 0x3025416a in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#23 0x308f0354 in -[UIApplication _run] ()
#24 0x308eea94 in UIApplicationMain ()
```

Comment: There coule be a great number of this that could cause this. There is now way to tell unless you test it on a device running iOS 3. If you do not have an iOS 3 device I would suggest to remove support voor iOS 3, just make the deployment target 4.0

Comment: I'm testing on 3.0 device - all works fine

Comment: I'm thinking maybe since `-[UINib instantiateWithOptions:owner:loadingResourcesFromBundle:]` is throwing an exception I'm guessing maybe your nib file is incompatible with iOS 4. Or is that impossible.

Comment: Yes I think so. But how I can check compability? Problem appears in release configuration. Debug works fine

Comment: I'm trying to fix this problem according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2495446/turn-off-or-fix-bounce-zoom-warning-from-iphone-xib-compilation But there is no result

Comment: I've solved my problem with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2495446/turn-off-or-fix-bounce-zoom-warning-from-iphone-xib-compilation and cleaning project and removing int from device. Now I've new question. If I'll send updated binary to AppStore does it will work with new xibs with lower deployment target?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. **I'm figured out**. Referencing [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2495446/turn-off-or-fix-bounce-zoom-warning-from-iphone-xib-compilation) I'm resolved problem. On Xcode 4 file settings appeared on the right view.

So, if you set **deployment target** of your app you must set also **deployment target of xib** files. In my case iOS deployment target was 3.0 and deployment target of xibs - are last SDK (5.0). I think automatic set deployment target for all xibs feature need to be implemented in Xcode.

Comment: Also, I've tested new version of app and had the same problem. Opening and re-saving all xibs fix the problem